# Kali 2.0: Run 32bit program on 64bit OS

Tags: debian, kali-linux

I  am trying to run some of the challenges from the Modern Binary Exploitation from RPISEC, (http://security.cs.rpi.edu/courses/binexp-spring2015/) but every time I try to run them it says `./crackme0x00a: No such file or directory.` I have looked through multiple questions that are already on StackExchange, but I can't seem to find any that work.

I have tried the answers to these questions: https://serverfault.com/questions/547371/how-to-install-32-bit-libraries-using-debian-testing and https://askubuntu.com/questions/454253/how-to-run-32-bit-app-in-ubuntu-64-bit but no luck, and it wont let me install any of the packages that it says to, such as libc6 and such. I am on Kali 2.0 64 bit (I think)

`root@kali:~# uname -m
x86_64`

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: so what's the challenge exactly, and aren't you supposed to work this out ?

Comment: No, the challenges are the files that I need to reverse engineer, but I cant even open them... I did some research that it may be because I'm on 64bit and trying to open 32bit executables, but it doesnt have anything to do with the challenge.

Comment: Ahh duh, right, okay make sure you have multilib packages installed.

Comment: So, what happened?

Comment: I tried installing the multilib packages, but I ran in to the same problem that I had before, they would not install. I tried to install `lib32z1 lib32ncurses5` like the other answers to the questions said, but it keeps giving me the errors `lib32z1 : Depends: libc6-i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
` and so on. Which multilib packages do I need for Kali 2.0? Thanks!\

Comment: From [here](http://docs.kali.org/development/arm-cross-compilation-environment) follow the guide for setting up an arm build environment. The packages may have changed some so look for the equivalent packages, pay special attention to the step for running `dpkg --add-architecture i386` and the additional steps afterward. If you did a proper install of the distro, after that you should be sorted.

Comment: I found that after some searching as well, but I ran into problems with the ia32-libs being outdated, and when I try to install the ones that it says replace it, it gives me the same errors that I had before. Any ideas? Thanks for your help btw!